# customize json response in graphQL

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

i use Express-js and express graphQL module to create my endpoint and web service ;

i am looking for way to create custom response in graphQL my endpoint is simple

select books from database my response is

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "id": "5b5c02beab8dc1182b2e0a03",
        "name": "dasta"
      },
      {
        "id": "5b5c02c0ab8dc1182b2e0a04",
        "name": "dasta"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but in need something like this

```
{
  "result": "success",
  "msg" : "list ...",
  "data": [
      {
        "id": "5b5c02beab8dc1182b2e0a03",
        "name": "dasta"
      },
      {
        "id": "5b5c02c0ab8dc1182b2e0a04",
        "name": "dasta"
      }
  ]
}
```

here is my bookType

```
const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: () => ({
        id: {type: GraphQLID},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        genre: {type: GraphQLString},
        author_id: {type: GraphQLString},
        author: {
            type: AuthorType,
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return Author.findById(parent.author_id);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a legal GraphQL response.  As per [section 7.1 of the spec](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/June2018/#sec-Response-Format), after describing the `data`, `errors`, and `extensions`: top-level keys:

> ... the top level response map must not contain any entries other than the three described above.

You might put this data into `extensions`; or make it an explicit part of your GraphQL API; or simply let "success" be implied by the presence of a result and the lack of an error.